# How to make a Qi charging mousepad for my mouse and keyboard?

Tags: pcb, coil, wireless-charging

[image: mousepad design]

This image shows my plan. Will this work, each of them being an individual charging circuit,or should I be combining the coils for each area into one circuit? If I need to combine, can I just solder a second set of three pack coils into parallel or do I need to be adding more?

Comment: what is the picture showing?

Comment: Its 4 independent qi transmitters 2 for the keyboard and 2 for the mouse, each transmitter has 3 coils.

Comment: why are you do this? ... is one charger insufficient for a mouse?